# Finding Parametric Equations for the right side of Hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections, parametrization

I have this equation $x^2-y^2=1$.

I can understand that it is a Hyperbola. But my question is, how can I create/find a parametric equation for the right side of this hyperbola? It seems it doesn't work, using $\sin$ or $\cos$. 
Thanks

Comment: You can use hyperbolic functions in place of trigonometric functions. i.e. $\cosh \theta$ and $\sinh\theta$.

Comment: @JohnDoe i edited my question. i forgot to mention that i need to write a parametric equation for the right side of the graph

Comment: [The wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Parametric_equations) on hyperbolas has several to choose from, although it won’t really help you develop them a priori. One possibility is to write the equation of the right branch in polar coordinates and then use slope ($\tan\theta$) as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find functions $x(t), y(t)$ that satisfy $x^2 - y^2 = 1$. Perhaps, if we rewrite as $x^2 = 1 + y^2$, that'll help.

This reminds me of Pythagorean identities. In particular, it reminds me of $1 + \tan^2(t) = \sec^2(t)$.

Trying $(x(t), y(t)) = (\sec(t), \tan(t))$ has the unfortunate side effect that we may get negative values for $x$, depending on what we allow for $t$ (but it can't be fixed by choosing a small range for $t$, without losing some of the right half). Try using $|\sec(t)|$ instead, to ensure that we only get positive $x$-values.

Answer (score 0):

Whit $r(t)=(x(t), y(t)) = (\sec(t), \tan(t))$ get the right branch, with $t \in\,]-\pi/2,\; \pi/2[$ (you can try for example $]-1.4,1.4[$). For the left branch you can try $r(t+\pi)$,  $t \in\,]-\pi/2,\; \pi/2[$.

Best is  $r(t)=(x(t), y(t)) = (\pm\cosh(t), \sinh(t))$, *one sign for each branch*. And you can use any interval $[-s,s]$. For example $r(t) = (\cosh(t), \sinh(t)), \; t \in\, [-1,1]$ and $r(0)$ is the vertex of the branch